# Will expanding metal disrupt my motion sensor?

Tags: sensors, metals

I am trying to install a door motion sensor in a environment that will get very hot for our work. So the door could heat up to temperature of 150-200°F. We built the frames and door to handle the expansion but what can we do about the motion sensor? In guess with temp that hot it will expand causing the alarm to constantly go off.

Comment: Wouldn't it also depend on the type of door motion sensor, where it is placed & why a door motion sensor is needed? Will both sides of the door, or the environment of either side be hot? Are you only considering electrical sensors or are are mechanical motion sensors an option?

Comment: Can you share the specification or model of the motion sensor?